# Heroku deployed app is not sending proper response while if I run heroku locally using heroku local web , I am getting proper response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, deploying

I am trying to deploy a node+express+mongo into heroku.

index.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3200;

const CONNECTION_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://aarthi:C<password>@cluster0.prt4u.mongodb.net/BookMyShow?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () =>
      console.log(
        `Server Running on Port:https://immense-sands-26614.herokuapp.com/`
      )
    )
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hackathon_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.6",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "validator": "^13.5.2"
  },"engines": {
    "node": "14.15.1"
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to run the node using local heroku using heroku local web

```
:47:13 pm web.1 |  [nodemon] 2.0.7
4:47:13 pm web.1 |  [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
4:47:13 pm web.1 |  [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
4:47:13 pm web.1 |  [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
4:47:13 pm web.1 |  [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
4:47:17 pm web.1 |  (node:33016) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
4:47:17 pm web.1 |  (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
4:47:17 pm web.1 |  Server Running on Port:https://immense-sands-26614.herokuapp.com/
```

while hitting the postman api req getting proper response

[api req when running locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K8M1.png)

But when I hit request for the deployed heroku app, Getting error
[Deployed Heroku app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr3Ow.png)

I saw what is running on console of deployed heroku, it  seems fine

[Console on web heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKGBx.png)

Not sure what the problem is. someone please help to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Finally figurred out the problem.

I am sending request via https:// which is not supported

changed my request url to http://...
http://immense-sands-26614.herokuapp.com/api/movies